# How does the Count() Method work in this code?

Tags: django, python-3.x, count

I have this piece of code from the book, I currently go through, don't know how but it works. I would love if someone could explain to me how Count('tags') know that it should only count tags that are connected to post.

```
def post_detail(request, year, day, month, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = post, publish__year = year, publish__month = month, publish__day = day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    post_tags_pks = post.tags.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_pks).exclude(pk=post.pk)
    similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]


    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post, 'comments': comments, 'comment_form': comment_form,'similar_posts': similar_posts})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django aggregation method **`Count()`** from **`django.db.models`** annotates to Count the number of Children which is related to it through ForeignKey.

You can have a look at **[Django Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/)**.

Below code will give the count of all tags that is related to the individual posts by annotating it.

```
similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]
```

You can access the count for any post using the variable where you stored the count.

In your case here, the below code will give the tags count for first post.

```
similar_posts[0].same_tags
```

Comment: @pawqo, did this help?

Comment: thanks, it is very helpful, idk why my previous comment got deleted, so thanks again :) @Astik Anand